# Replace character in nested Struct Type Column using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe with following schema.

```
root
 |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- col4: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col41: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col411: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col42: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col421: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col422: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col4221: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- col423: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col4231: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col4232:SPL1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col4233:SPL2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col4234:SPL3: string (nullable = true)
```

I would want to replace a special character in the key. In this example I would want to replace ":" with "_" for `col4232:SPL1, Col4233:SPL2 and col4234:SPL3`. I will need an output as shown below. And there are many columns that I would want to perform this replace, so the columns in the structure are dynamic in nature.

```
root
 |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- col4: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col41: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col411: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col42: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col421: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col422: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col4221: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- col423: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col4231: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col4232_SPL1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col4233_SPL2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col4234_SPL3: string (nullable = true)
```

Any help in this regards will be truly helpful.